# Quick Sort с использованием boost coroutine

Tags: c++, boost, coroutine

Есть задание написать алгоритм быстрой сортировки с использованием сопрограмм из библиотеки boost. Вроде написал, но получается, что он по времени сортирует дольше чем без использования сопрограмм. Хотя в теории должен быстрее.
Подскажите, что не так делаю?

---

```
template <class T>
using vector_t = std::vector<T>;
using coro_t = boost::coroutines2::coroutine<int32_t>;

template <class T>
void partition(coro_t::push_type& sink, vector_t<T>& v, int32_t left, int32_t right) {
    int32_t pivot = v[right];
    int32_t i = (left - 1);

    for (int32_t j = left; j <= right - 1; j++) {
        if (v[j] <= pivot) {
            i++;
            std::swap(v[i], v[j]);
        }
    }
    std::swap(v[i + 1], v[right]);
    sink(i + 1);
}

template <class T>
void quickSort(vector_t<T>& v, int32_t left, int32_t right) {
    if (left <= right) {
        coro_t::pull_type source{[&](auto &&arg1) {
            partition(arg1, v, left, right);
            quickSort(v, left, source.get() - 1);
            quickSort(v, source.get() + 1, right);
        }};
        source();
    }
}

int main() {
    vector_t<int32_t> v(10);
    std::cin >> v;
    std::cout <<"Vector before:\n" << v << std::endl;
    clock_t t = clock();
    quickSort(v, 0, v.size() - 1);
    t = clock() - t;
    std::cout << std::fixed << ((double) t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Vector after:\n" << v << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: во-первых, слишком маленький вектор, чтобы оценить время... а во-вторых, что-то не пойму, как сопрограммы могут помочь сделать сортировку быстрее?

Comment: Для оценки времени вектор брался разных размеров. А на счет ускорения сортировки, это лишь мое, возможно ошибочное, предположение, основанное на моих предыдущих экспериментах с сопрограммами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Корутины работают в одном потоке, они в любом случае будут работать медленнее (на их создание всё же затрачивается время). Они дают преимущество только при асинхронных операциях.

Для ускорения нужны либо многопоточные корутины (в boost вроде бы есть что-то подобное), либо банальный пул потоков. Если хотите добиться ускорения - я бы рекомендовал сначала реализовать быструю сортировку с использованием `std::async` и посмотреть, получится ли вообще ускорение при распараллеливании. Для малых векторов точно не получится, результаты должны быть видны при сортировке примерно тысячи небольших строк (сортировка строк лучше демонстрирует применимость в реальных программах, для сортировки int вряд ли вообще нужна многопоточность).